# after facebook login page doesn't reload in ie

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

In my aspx page i have facebook login button in a modal popup. When user clicks on that and logs in  i am capturing login details using facebook C# sdk. before login i am showing login div and after login showine user div.

It works fine with all the browsers except IE. Where after logging in the modal popup closes but page doesn't reload. locally it works fine even in IE. but in facebook app after login user div doesn't show.   Please help.

```
aspx code below
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:Reload();" scope="email,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access" onclick="document.getElementById('divWait').style.display = 'block';"  >Login with Facebook</div>
```

My javascript code is below.

```
    <script >       (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=221678077921242"; 
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
      appId: '311257055585019', 
         channelUrl: '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
         status: true, // check login status
         cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
         oauth: true
      });

   };

   (function(d) {
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   } (document));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Reload() {
      window.location.href = "urlred.aspx?page=delmode.aspx&fb=1";
   }

</script>
```

my asp.net code  below

```
FacebookWebContext wc = new FacebookWebContext(new FBSettings() { AppId = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LogApi"].ToString(), AppSecret = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LogSecret"].ToString() });
          Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient cl = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient(wc);
          if ((wc.Session != null && wc.Session.AccessToken != null && iLogin == 1))
          {Facebook.JsonObject fbUser = (Facebook.JsonObject)cl.Get("/me");
             if (fbUser.Count > 0)
             {
                //do other work
             }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the channel url to an actual value. You can't use the default value of:

```
channelUrl: '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
```

Add a channel.html file to your site and set the value appropriately. You can find out more about the channel file on Facebook's developer docs.